# How to call controller action from blade file, same like action do?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

//Blog controller

```
class BlogController extends BaseController
{

    //Home page blog
    public static function HomePageBlogs()
    {
        return view('pages.Blog.homepage_blog');
    }
}
```

How can I call HomePageBlogs from home.blade.php?

Comment: Make a call via ajax and that will return a view (pages.Blog.homepage_blog). Basically, the add that response to an element.

Comment: To call partial view include('view name') has been use.@Digvijay There should be functionality to call controller action from blade file.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to call controller action from view file you can use ajax